# Nginx as reverse proxy / load balancer: Is cookie based sticky supported?

Tags: nginx

The real question: To get sticky-cookie functionality, is it necessary to use nginx commercial subscription?

This doc seems to indicate yes: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky
(note the tag at the bottom of the entry for "sticky" keyword)

But this doc makes the upstream functionality appear included:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

I am getting confused. It appears that the upstream module is part of the FOSS flavor, but some directives require commercial subscription? (And "sticky" is a directive that requires commercial subscription?)

Comment: There are also third party modules that provide sticky functionality.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. I may have to take that path. I kinds don't love cobbling the system from third party pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I was researching the same thing and I was equally confused reading the docs, so I checked the source and `sticky` is not bundled with the main open source bundle:

```
$ wget -qO - http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.12.tar.gz | tar xz -O | grep -c sticky
0
```

I may just try haproxy...

Comment: I have also started converting to haproxy. For the same reason. I respect their desire to charge, but have wasted too much time on understanding where I stand on the foss version.